# Yahoo Pipes, preserving HTML in RSS item builder

Tags: xml, yahoo-pipes

I am using “XPath fetch page” to get a subtree of a DOM tree of a web page. I'd like to put that subtree unmodified into the RSS (with all tags, links etc.) I am using “RSS Item Builder” to make an RSS item, but it seems that the module strips all tags from the input. This way all the links are lost. What should I do to keep the elements?

The pipe I'm working on: [Tatoeba Wall posts](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=508470e4e64dfe2b6b21d2f3f140efee). The penultimate element is a looped “RSS Item Builder” which should put a subtree stored in `item.message` as the description field of an item. For example, an item (screenshot of a debugger tracking the element right before the “RSS Item Builder”):

[image]

will be converted by “RSS Item Builder”:

[image]

to:

[image]

where the `item.description` element no longer contains any html.